# Unix: `look` with numerically sorted keys

Tags: sorting, unix, search, grep, binary-search

I'm trying to use `look` to speed up searches from a sorted file. My understanding of `look` is that it workes where the input data (up to some terminator specified by `-t`) is sorted. My data is numerically sorted, which it doesn't seem to like.

My `look` is `look from util-linux 2.23.2`. Is there any way I can make it play nicely with my numerically sorted data?

Small reproducible example:

```
$ seq 100 | sed "s/$/,[data]/" > temp                                                                     
$ look 11 temp
$ look 11, temp
$ look -t, 11 temp
$ look -d 11 temp
$ look -d -t, 11 temp
$ look -f -d -t, 11 temp
```

`look` finds nothing. `grep` works just fine.

```
$ grep 11 temp
11,[data]
```

Comment: All of the above `look` commands returned `11,[data]` for me.

Comment: @JamesBrown can I ask version you're working with?

Comment: Yeah no idea. There is no version switch, `strings` doesn't reveal anything either. I came with Debian's Bsdmainutils Version: 9.0.12+nmu1. Update: IT did, I didn't. :D